# Unity Interception and WCF RIA Domain Services

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, ria

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to use Unity Interception on a RIA Domain Service and if so how it can be done.

I already have a custom DomainServiceFactory which is used to create requested Domain Services allowing me to use Unity to inject dependencies via the Domain Service constructor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. The only restrictions with Unity Interceptors is that you either have to have an interface to intercept, which don't come with RIA domain services out of the box, or that the class is not sealed and has virtual methods, which should apply to RIA services.